# Kivy on Android: Keep Kivy clock running even when app is minimized

Tags: android, python, kivy

My Android app contains a timer using Kivy's Clock function.

I want the timer to keep ticking even when the app has been minimized by pressing the home button. The on_pause method is not what I'm looking for as the timer continues where it left off when you minimized the app.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not directly possible, and indeed on android you must always account for the possibility that the OS will close your app while it is paused. You can instead use a [service](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.org/en/latest/android/#service-android-service) to do more continuous stuff while the app is paused, and/or take account of those changes when the app is unpaused.